# Data rendering in blade using foreach loop

Tags: laravel-5.7

This code should list all of the missing majors from the database to the blade file. The database query successfully retrieves the correct data, but it is not rendering in the blade?

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($majors_array1);$i++)
{ if (School::where('major', '=', $majors_array1[$i])->exists()) 
{ echo $majors_array1[$i] . '       ' ." found"."<br/>";}
else
{ return view('enter-school-dept')->with('majors_array1', 
$majors_array1[$i]);}
}
<table>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>School</th></tr>
<tr>
@foreach (majors_array1 as $majors) 
<td>$majors</td>
@endforeach
</tr>
</table>
```

ex-
CSE
EEE

I am getting the error:

```
Use of undefined constant majors_array1 - assumed 'majors_array1' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\enter-school-dept.blade.php)
```

Comment: Getting error Use of undefined constant majors_array1 - assumed 'majors_array1' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\enter-school-dept.blade.php)

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your foreach:

```
@foreach (majors_array1 as $majors) 
<td>$majors</td>
@endforeach
```

With:

```
@foreach ($majors_array1 as $major) 
<td>{{ $major }}</td>
@endforeach
```